# How to enable curse words voice recognition in Google Keep app?

Tags: ipad, google, voice-dictation, word-processor

I can't find the definition to enable curse words voice recognition on my Google Keep app for iPad , iOS 10 .

It's not possible to change this ?
I tested on multiple languages and it's using ***** for curse in multiple languages...

Can you help?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Does that app allow you to use Apple's voice dictation feature in the built in keyboard?

Comment: Thank you! I gonna try it, didn't remembered about that!

Comment: Yeah it works with the keyboard, but using the microphone icon at Google keep using the specific function it doesn't work, how can I fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Short of getting Google to allow you to transcribe words (check if you are in a school or work google account setting) you will need to use Apple's dictation if Google's doesn't let you curse.

Comment: How do I configure that ?

Comment: It's not a school or work account, this is actually my personal iPad.. thank you